# How to change orientation of interactive marker of cartesian path planner?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a 6DOF arm and I have configured move_it for the arm in indigo. I am using the  cartesian path planner plugin to define waypoints for the arm. But the  interactive marker from the plugin is not aligning with the end effector axis.

[image: C:\fakepath\d2.png]

In this picture, you can see that the endeffector is facing upwards but the marker is not aligned with the axis of end effector.
How to make the interactive marker point the correct axis?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254808/how-to-change-orientation-of-interactive-marker-of-cartesian-path-planner?/) by [Gokul](https://answers.ros.org/users/25955/gokul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 243 on 2017-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Explanation**: I am explaining it as per my understanding. If it is wrong, please correct me.
The arrow head in the interactive marker is always aligned with the x-axis of the last joint. But the last joint of my arm has the end effector attached to it along the z-axis(rotation axis). Since the arrow head always points the x-axis, the end effector and the arrowhead where not aligned.

**Solution:**
I opened the SolidWorks model of the arm and changed the coordinate system for the last joint having the rotational axis as the x-axis. Now the arrow head is aligned with the end effector because now it rotates along the x-axis.
[C:\fakepath\sol.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/1487308767592536.png)

---

Originally posted by [Gokul](https://answers.ros.org/users/25955/gokul/) with karma: 243 on 2017-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0